# Data from NFC chip contains strange symbols? Android/Java

Tags: java, android

I hope someone can help me, this is the situation:

I have a NFC chip (Mifare Classic 4k) and I read some of the information out ( It's a school-card, so I read out the student number e.g.)

When I read it out, and place it in my textView like this:

mTextView.setText(cardData);

I get this:
"1330955"

When I write it out in System.out.println() like this:

System.out.println(cardData);

I get this:
"1330955????????????????"

When I tried to put it in a database through JDBC and PreparedStatement like this:

```java
            try {
                String sql = "insert into studentCards (studentNumber, title, firstName, lastName, dateOfBirth, gender)" + " VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(5);
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

                PreparedStatement pStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                pStatement.setInt(1, cardData);
                pStatement.setString(2, title);
                pStatement.setString(3, firstName);
                pStatement.setString(4, lastName);
                pStatement.setString(5, dateOfBirth);
                pStatement.setString(6, gender);

                int rs = pStatement.executeUpdate();
                return retval = Integer.toString(rs);


            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return retval = e.toString();
            } finally {
                System.out.println("Closing the connection.");
                if (conn != null) try { conn.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
            }
```

I got this:

"1330955\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0" as student number...

I tried everything... How can I just get the number (1330955) in the database?
I even tried to use the split() function, but that doesn't work.

Can one of you please help me? If you need more information, please let me know!

**Solved!**

I had to use .trim() on cardData.

Comment: did you tried cardData.trim() ?

Comment: Thanks that worked! I don't know how to thank you! I've been struggling with this for like 4 or 5 hours...

Comment: No problem, Just mark as right answer.

Comment: How do I mark it as a right answer if it's a comment? (I'm new to Stackoverflow)

Comment: yeah sorry I just commented not answered :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the method trim() from java native class String